# Array formula to switch selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to determine the top 3 depending on the selected criteria, amount or count. User can choose between the two. I have the formula to determine top 3 but I don't know how to modify it to take in account of user's selection. User's selection is in `J2`.

In this case, count is selected but as you can see, my formula spits out amount.

I think I need an array formula nesting `choose` or `offset` or something. The formula I have in the selected cell is

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$35,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$3:$E$35=LARGE($E$3:$E$35,ROWS(I$7:I7)))*(COUNTIF(I$7:I7,$A$3:$A$35)=0),),0))
```

which calculates top 3. How can I get that to change depending on user selection?

[image]

Edit: I realize I can have two sets of data for each criteria and do an `offset` to select between the two but figured one of you wizards can probably do it all in one. (This data is used to drive a graph.)

Edit2: sorry if it was too abstract. There are two columns. E and F. E is a list of amounts. F is a list of counts. I want to find the top 3 of both. But obviously only one at a time. Depending on what the user chooses.

As you can see, even though the selection is currently count (J7), the results show the top 3 by amounts.

By using the number selected in `J2`, I should be able to nest an `offset` function to grab the column desired yes? 1 for column E, 2 for column F. That's how I understand the function to work. However, my attempts to nest has failed because I believe I need an array formula which is beyond my skillz.

Edit3: see pic. It shows the top 3 by each criteria. How do I combine them?

[image]

Comment: I do not fully understand your question.  Its possible that the data not shown in Columns A-D would help.

Comment: Agree ^ seeing the full data set will likely help. It would also be useful if you can explain in laymens terms what you aim to do here? Top 3 of what based on what?

Comment: I want to determine the top 3 either by amount or count depending on what the user chooses. What top 3 is is irrelevant yes? My formula currently looks at column E which is amount. I should be able to nest `offset` or something to look at column F instead which is count. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What's in column A? Doesn't your formula just have to reference F instead of E for the count? i.e. `=IF(J2=1, E stuff, otherwise F stuff)`.

Comment: @SJR OH SNAP. If statement! That should work. I totally over thinked it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine it into one (non-array) formula. Here is a simple example which perhaps you can adapt to your situation.

This is the formula in J7. Change the 2 in J2 to 1 and it will return the largest value in E rather than F.

`=INDEX(OFFSET($E$3:$E$35,,J2-1,,),MATCH(1,INDEX((OFFSET($E$3:$E$35,,J2-1,,)=LARGE(OFFSET($E$3:$E$35,,J2-1,,),ROWS(I$7:I7)))*COUNTIF(I$7:I7,$A$3:$A$35)=0),),0))`

[image]